# Destructor called when objects are passed by value

Tags: c++

> Even though objects are passed to functions by means of the normal
>   call-by-value parameter passing mechanism, which, in theory, protects
>   and insulates the calling argument, it is still possible for a side
>   effect to occur that may affect, or even damage, the object used as an
>   argument. For example, if an object used as an argument allocates
>   memory and frees that memory when it is destroyed, then its local copy
>   inside the function will free the same memory when its destructor is
>   called. This will leave the original object damaged and effectively
>   useless.

This is written in C++: The Complete Reference

In this program here

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

class Sample
{         
 public:
         int *ptr;
         Sample(int i)
         {
         ptr = new int(i);
         }
         ~Sample()
         {
         cout<<"destroyed";
         delete ptr;
         }
         void PrintVal()
         {
         cout << "The value is " << *ptr;
         }
 };
 void SomeFunc(Sample x)
{
 cout << "Say i am in someFunc " << endl;
}
 int main()
{
 Sample s1= 10;
SomeFunc(s1);
 s1.PrintVal();
}
```

It generates a runtime error as the object s1 is destroyed when it returns from the object. I couldnt figure out why this might happen, since a copy should have been made.
I thought maybe it was because there was no copy constructor present in the class defination. But i was surprised to find that if use this function declaration

```
 void SomeFunc(Sample &x)
{
 cout << "Say i am in someFunc " << endl;
}
```

In this declaration no error occurs. Shouldnt the error occur here as well because it is referenced?
Can anyone explain what happens in both cases.

Comment: Do you undertsand what pass by reference means?

Comment: good example of why copy constructors are useful

Comment: @Claptrap Rather a good example of why you shouldn't handle the memory yourself and let a smart pointer do it. Better than the rule of three/five is the [**rule of zero**](http://flamingdangerzone.com/cxx11/2012/08/15/rule-of-zero.html)

Comment: @JBL in some situations it is not possible to use a smart pointer e.g. legacy code or process rules.

Comment: @Claptrap Of course, but as OP is not in this case but rather learning, let's point _first_ at modern practices, and _then_ if the need arise, to legacy hacks :)

Comment: @JBL it is not a hack doing a copy constructor. I am not quite sure why you go on about smart pointers, i don't disagree that it is the best practice, but that is not what he is asking for. He is just asking why it doesn't work

Comment: @Claptrap I would argue that in modern C++ you have most of the time better alternative than writing a copy constructor. Which is good because it avoids many traps related to the rule of three/five.

Comment: @JBL There is nothing to argue about, smart pointers *is* the best practice.

Comment: *side effect* has a different meaning in C++. This text smells of bullSchildt.

Comment: @Claptrap [I covered it](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25969933/211160) as well as other overlooked points.  :-)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This is indeed because you didn't provide a copy constructor. Thus the compiler will generate one for you, which does trivial copy. And that's the trivial copy of the pointer that's problematic here.

For the following declaration

```
void SomeFunc(Sample x);
```

There will be indeed a copy when you pass `s1` to the function, but this copy will have a copy of the pointer, that is, the two object will point to the same `int`.

Then, when exiting the function, the copy will be destroyed and will delete that pointer, leaving the original object in the calling code with a pointer just deleted (remember, they point to the same thing).

Then, for the following declaration

```
void SomeFunc(Sample &x);
```

you don't have any copy, thus the problem doesn't show up. Indeed, passing by reference means that inside the function, the `Sample` object you're manipulating is exactly the same as the one you passed to the function, and won't be destroyed when the function exits.

Comment: +1 Great answer! It is always worth remembering the [Rule of 3](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three)

Comment: [Rule of 0](https://blog.rmf.io/cxx11/rule-of-zero) would be superior if you can avoid the rule of 3 (or 5, post C++11)

Answer (score 4):

I'll give an answer more from the Modern C++ perspective of "avoid raw pointers if you can".  But I'll also point out an important distinction you should be aware of:

[C++ constructor syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/587070/c-constructor-syntax)

But first, let's consider what your intention is.  If I wrote:

```
Sample x = 1;
Sample y = x;
```

What should be the semantics?

> Should the `Sample` "copies" each have their own independent 'ptr', whose pointed-to object lifetime lasts only as long as the class they they live in?

It's usually the case that you do not need pointers at all if this is what you want.

Most of the time, the total class size will be reasonable enough that stack allocation won't be a problem if you are declaring them without `new` *(as you are here)*.  So why get pointers involved?  Just use `int i` (or whatever your non-[POD](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/146452/what-are-pod-types-in-c) class is).

If you actually have the kind of case where you *do* need to dynamically allocate large blocks of data to manage yourself *(vs. deferring to C++ library collections or similar)*, those might [exceed your stack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79923/).  If you need to dynamically allocate, you're going to need copy construction one way or another.  That means `Sample` will need to explicitly manage the copy construction -or- use a [smart pointer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/106508/what-is-a-smart-pointer-and-when-should-i-use-one) class that finesses it so it *doesn't have to*.

First let's say you're keeping the raw pointer, that would mean:

```
Sample(const Sample & other)
{
   ptr = new int(*other.ptr);
}
```

*BUT* you could reduce the potential for error in this situation by using a `unique_ptr` instead.  A unique_ptr will destroy the data pointed to by the raw pointer it's holding automatically when its destructor runs.  So you don't have to worry about calling `delete`.

*Also*, a unique_ptr will refuse to copy by default.  Hence if you just wrote:

```
class Sample
{         
public:
     unique_ptr<int> ptr;
     Sample(int i)
     {
         ptr = std::unique_ptr<int>(new int(i));
     }
     ~Sample()
     {
        cout << "destroyed";
     }
     void PrintVal()
     {
         cout << "The value is " << *ptr;
     }
};
```

The class itself can build, but you would get errors at your callsites.  They would point out that you're making copies for something that copy construction has not been properly defined for.  Not only that...you aren't just making *one* copy in your program, but *two*:

```
In function ‘int main()’:
error: use of deleted function ‘Sample::Sample(const Sample&)’
Sample s1 = 10;
            ^
note: ‘Sample::Sample(const Sample&)’ is implicitly deleted
       because the default definition would be ill-formed:

error: use of deleted function ‘Sample::Sample(const Sample&)’
SomeFunc(s1);
           ^
```

That gives you a heads up to add a copy constructor equivalent to:

```
     Sample(const Sample & other)
     {
         ptr = std::unique_ptr<int>(new int(*other.ptr));
     }
```

Plus you probably want to change `Sample s1 = 10;` to `Sample s1 (10);` to avoid the copy there.  For that matter, you may well have wanted `SomeFunc` to take its values by reference as well.  I'll also mention looking into [initializer lists vs assignments](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/init-lists.html).

*(Note: There's actually a name for the pattern of a smart pointer class that copies called `clone_ptr`, so you wouldn't have to write even **that** copy constructor.  It's not in the standard C++ library but [you'll find implementations around](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8318177/211160).)*

> Should the `Sample` "copies" share a common dynamic `ptr` that is deleted only after the last reference goes away?

Easier with smart pointers, and no copy constructor needed on Sample at all.  Use a `shared_ptr`.  The default behavior of a shared_ptr is to be able to be copied with simple assignments.

```
class Sample
{         
public:
     shared_ptr<int> ptr;
     Sample(int i)
     {
         ptr = make_shared<int>(i);
     }
     ~Sample()
     {
        cout << "destroyed";
     }
     void PrintVal()
     {
         cout << "The value is " << *ptr;
     }
};
```

Moral of the story is that the more you can let the default behaviors do the correct work for you...and the less code you write...the less potential you have for bugs.  So while it's good to know what copy constructors do and when they are invoked, it can be equally important to know how to *not* write them!

Note that unique_ptr and shared_ptr are from C++11, and will require `#include <memory>`.

Answer (score 0):

Your object was copied field by field, so inside `SomeFunc` you have two instances of `Sample` - `s1` and `x` (but only `x` is accessible), and value of `x.ptr` is equal to `s1.ptr`. Then when `SomeFunc` ends, destructor is called and from that point `s1.ptr` points to unallocated memory. Its called "dangling pointer".