# Assigning a new size to a dynamic array in a class - A question from a test

Tags: c++, computer-science

I'm trying to figure out why in this piece of code, every time the function `f()` is called, the function calls the destructor and does not reallocate the size of the array

I know if I change it to `int f(A & a) { return 2 * a.n; }`
it will work, but I still don't understand why it goes into the destructor.

```
class A {
   public:
    A(int i = 10) {
        n = i;
        p = new int[n];
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
            p[j] = 0;
        }
    }
    ~A() { delete p; }
    int n;
    int* p;
};
int f(A a) { return 2 * a.n; }

int main() {
    A a1(5), a2(5);
    cout << 1 << endl;
    f(a1);
    cout << 2 << endl;
    f(a2);
    cout << 3 << endl;
    f(a1);
    cout << 4 << endl;
    f(a2);
}
```

---

Comment: I hope this code is not from a test. The `delete p` is **wrong**. That should have been a `delete[]`.

Comment: Also see [rule of three](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172722/what-is-the-rule-of-three).

Comment: @JasonLiam: The Rule of Three is relevant here, but it does not answer the question.

Comment: @MSalters Ok, I've added more dupes that explain what happens when we pass argument by value.

Comment: I think I found a more direct duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25968902/destructor-called-when-objects-are-passed-by-value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every time `f(A a)` returns, the parameter `a` used in the call is destroyed.

Comment: So every time the function is called it creates a copy and releases p at the end of the block?

Comment: @yoavlv12: Indeed, it releases `a.p`. But that is a direct copy of either `a1.p` or `a2.p`, so you release the memory of **another** object. That's why Jason Liam pointed out the Rule of Three. `class A` needs a copy constructor (or better. a `std::vector` - that would have solved all the problems here)